'dispatch' is declared but its value is never read
'dispatch' is declared but its value is never read
this is the code where I'm using this:
actions/index.js
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
export function SignInAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    auth
      .SignInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
}

and then in Login.js as:
import styled from "styled-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { SignInAPI } from "../actions";
const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Nav>
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/images/login-logo.svg" alt="" />
        </a>
        <div>
          <Join>Join now</Join>
          <SignIn>SignIn</SignIn>
        </div>
      </Nav>
      <Section>
        <Hero>
          <h1>Welcome to your professional community</h1>
          <img src="images/login-hero.svg" alt="hero" />
        </Hero>
        <Form>
          {/* //this is where the issue arises. */}
          <Google onClick={()=>props.SignIn()}>
            <img src="images/google.svg" alt="google" />
            Sign in with Google
          </Google>
        </Form>
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 0px;
`;
const Nav = styled.nav`
  max-width: 1128px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px 0 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

  & > a {
    width: 135px;
    height: 34px;
    @media (max-width: 786px) {
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
  }
`;
const Join = styled.a`
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`;

const SignIn = styled.a`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #0a66c2;
  color: #0a66c2;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition-duration: 167ms;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* transition: ; */
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(112, 181, 249, 0.15);
    color: #0a66c2;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`;

const Section = styled.section`
  display: flex;
  align-content: start;
  min-height: 700px;
  padding-bottom: 138px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding: 60px 0;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1128px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
`;

const Hero = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    width: 55%;
    font-size: 56px;
    color: #2977c9;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 70px;
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 2;
    }
  }

  img {
    width: 700px;
    height: 670px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    right: -150px;
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      top: 230px;
      width: initial;
      position: initial;
      height: initial;
    }
  }
`;
const Form = styled.div`
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 408px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
`;
const Google = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  height: 56px;
  width: 115%;
  border-radius: 28px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 60%),
    inset 0 0 0 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0);
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 0;
  transition-duration: 167ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.25);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
`;

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return;
};

// const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
//   singIn: () =>dispatchEvent(SignInAPI()),
// });

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{signIn:SignInAPI()})(Login);
// export default Login;

and in Login.js i get the error of that '''props:SignIn()''' is not a function.
Idk where I'm doing wrong and why isn't it reading the value .
I tried which i commented out in the Login.js file at the end.

Issue 1

'dispatch' is declared but its value is never read this is the code
where I'm using this: actions/index.js
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";

export function SignInAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    auth
      .SignInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
}


This is because dispatch is declared and it is not used at all. Fix this by removing the variable declaration. Since the SignInAPI action creator isn't dispatching any further actions there is no need to declare the passed dispatch variable.
export function SignInAPI() {
  return () => {
    auth
      .SignInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
}

Issue 2

Login.js I get the error of that props:SignIn() is not a
function.

This is because there is no passed SignIn prop, but you have passed a signIn prop via the connect Higher Order Component.

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signIn: SignInAPI() })(Login);


You should reference props.signIn here, and you should not immediately invoke the SignInAPI action.
Example Fix:
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state./* whatever state you are selecting */;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  singIn: SignInAPI, // get's wrapped in call to dispatch already 
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

Additional Suggestion
This all said, the style of Redux you are using here is extremely outdated. Modern Redux no longer uses the connect HOC, we use the useDispatch and useSelector hooks.
An example re-write might look like the following:
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { SignInAPI } from "../actions";

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch= useDispatch();

  const {
    /* whatever state you selected */
  } = useSelector(state => state./* whatever state you are selecting */);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Nav>
        <a href="/">
          <img src="/images/login-logo.svg" alt="" />
        </a>
        <div>
          <Join>Join now</Join>
          <SignIn>SignIn</SignIn>
        </div>
      </Nav>
      <Section>
        <Hero>
          <h1>Welcome to your professional community</h1>
          <img src="images/login-hero.svg" alt="hero" />
        </Hero>
        <Form>
          <Google onClick={() => dispatch(SignInAPI())}>
            <img src="images/google.svg" alt="google" />
            Sign in with Google
          </Google>
        </Form>
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
};

